# Query on two tables with belongs_to/has_many relation

Tags: mysql, sql

One table is `Users` with `id` and `email` columns.

Another table is `Payments` with `id`, `created_at`, `user_id` and `foo` columns.

`User` has many `Payments`.

I need a query that returns each user's `email`, his last `payment` date and this last payment's `foo` value. How do I do that? What I have now is:

```
SELECT users.email, MAX(payments.created_at), payments.foo
FROM users
JOIN payments ON payments.user_id = users.id
GROUP BY users.id
```

This is wrong, because `foo` value does not necessarily belong to user's most recent payment.

Comment: Add a `WHERE payments.created_at = MAX(payments.created_at)` and use `INNER JOIN`

Comment: @hjpotter92 `SELECT users.email, MAX(payments.created_at), payments.foo
FROM users
INNER JOIN payments ON payments.user_id = users.id
WHERE payments.created_at = MAX(payments.created_at)
GROUP BY users.id` throws an error: `invalid use of group function`

Comment: sorry, it'd be `HAVING payments.created_at = MAX(payments.created_at)`

Comment: That won't work too: `SELECT users.email, MAX(payments.created_at), payments.foo
FROM users
JOIN payments ON payments.user_id = users.id
GROUP BY users.id
HAVING payments.created_at = MAX(payments.created_at)` throws `Unknown column 'payments.created_at' in 'having clause'`

Comment: What is your PK in payments table?

Comment: @RubahMalam It's `id`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
select users.email,foo,create_at
from users
left join(
    select a.* from payments a
    inner join (
        select id,user_id,max(create_at)
        from payments
        group by id,user_id
    )b on a.id = b.id
) payments on users.id = payments.user_id
```

If users has no payment yet, then foo and create_at would return NULL. if you want to exclude users who has no payment, then use INNER JOIN.

Comment: I get `Duplicate column name 'id'`

Comment: @pmichna I updated the answer. Adding `a.*` in subquery.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use a MySQL version of rank over partition and then select only those rows with rank = 1:

```
select tt.email,tt.created_at,tt.foo from (
 select t.*,
 case when @cur_id = t.id then @r:=@r+1 else @r:=1 end as rank,
 @cur_id := t.id
 from (
  SELECT users.id,users.email, payments.created_at, payments.foo
  FROM users
  JOIN payments ON payments.user_id = users.id
  order by users.id asc,payments.created_at desc
 ) t
 JOIN (select @cur_id:=-1,@r:=0) r
) tt
where tt.rank =1;
```

This would save hitting the `payments` table twice. Could be slower though. Depends on your data!